# How to output individual tree results for a GBM model, using the POJO file created in H2O.ai?

Tags: h2o, gbm

I just have a POJO model file and the genModel.jar delivered to me. I need to figure out a way to output the individual tree results for that. Please guide me which wrapper and methods to use if this is supported in the POJO model.

Comment: did you manage to do that?